# Traceback Error When Importing bsp

Tags: import

I'm following this tutorial on how to import stuff from Source to Blender.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX5mzUeZJDo

But when I try to import a map (bsp) I get this error.

[image]

I get this error when importing from SFM and TF2. I don't know what I can do. Everywhere else I go I get ignored so I'm trying my luck here.

Comment: Hello, are you using the same version as in the tutorial ? (2.83.4)

Comment: No, I'm using 2.9

Comment: Try using the same version. Often times new versions break certain add-ons